# What is the correct way to include GLEW in a Mac OS X .framework?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, sdl, glew

Probably a very simple problem, but it's had me stumped.

I've got an SDL/OpenGL/GLEW based static library that compiles (gcc/g++) and links fine on Windows. On OS X, the same codebase fails to compile claiming that it can't find the declaration of GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS and ::glGetStringi() - which is since I've thrown GLEW in the mix (with only SDL and OpenGL, it builds fine on OS X too).

```
// globals.h
#include <glew.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

// graphics.h
#include "globals.h"

bool HasGLExtension(const char* pName);

// graphics.cpp
#include <string>
#include "graphics.cpp"

bool HasGLExtension(const char* pName)
{
  GLint numExtensions;
  ::glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &numExtensions); // error
  for (int i = 0; i < numExtensions; ++i)
  {
    if (strcmp(pName, (char*)::glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, i)) == 0) // error
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

- the dependent libraries, built as frameworks, are situated at /Library/Frameworks.
- the -DGLEW_STATIC -DSDL_NO_GLEXT compile flags are used (as needed on Windows - the problem persists even if I remove them).
- even auto-completion confirms that the location of glew.h exists (then again, of course, that's not the error I'm getting -- it's the symbols).
- including SDL/SDL_opengl.h will just result in conflicting declarations.
- the problematic definitions are present in glew.h

What's the obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: If you include `<string>` anyway, why don't you use `std::string`?

Comment: Why not quote the error given by the compiler? Also, why use the namespace scope `::glGetStringi` for a GLEW C function?

Comment: @Brett Hale: the project itself is a C++ library, and I'm in the habit of indicating stuff belonging to the global namespace as such.

Comment: @daknok_t: benefits > drawbacks in doing so. openGL works with c-strings, and since I'm not copying, modifying, creating the string programmatically, etc. I'm happy to do the same. Even though this isn't performance sensitive code (won't be checking for extensions in my game loop...), I prefer only copying a pointer where a pointer is enough, which also means not calling constructors that might or might not do obscure stuff, such as allocating memory.

Comment: @iCE-9 - So what *are* the errors given by the compiler?

Comment: @Brett: in essence "The symbol [...] has not been declared", for both symbols.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't do it. For something that 1, is easy to set up and 2, works out of the box and 3, has little to no encumbrance in its licensing, use [glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home).

Comment: Would the -1er care to explain the issue they had, and possibly make an improved suggestion?